# Drop down Menu in horizontal style

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to create a drop down menu in horizontal style in CSS
when you hover over the products, drop down menu will pop in horizontal

1st one:

Home | About | **product** | Contact

**Apple | Banana | Orange | berry | pear**

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

2nd one:

Home

About

**Product - Apple | Banana | Orange | berry | pear**

Contact

Comment: Same way you would do it with a vertical list, but `display: inline` on the `<li>` items.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there, you should google it before asking.http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/ http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

Considering you want horizontal type of dropdowns and considering you might want to add submenus to it. Here is an example.

[Horizontal Dropdown Menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_tabs/)